# In Java, when is the constructor for an enumerated constant invoked?

Tags: java, enums, constructor

To use a contrived example in Java, here's the code:

```
enum Commands{
   Save("S");
   File("F");

   private String shortCut;
   private Commands(String shortCut){ this.shortCut = shortCut; }
   public String getShortCut(){ return shortCut; }
}
```

I have the following test/driver code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   System.out.println(Commands.Save.getShortCut());
}
```

The question is: 
In Java, when is the constructor for an enumerated constant invoked? In the above example, I am only using the `Save` enumerated constant. Does this mean that the constructor is called once to create `Save` only? Or will both `Save` and `File` be constructed together regardless?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The constructors are invoked when the `enum` class is initialized. Each constructor will be invoked, in member declaration order, regardless of which members are actually referenced and used.

Comment: Does that mean when the `ClassLoader` loads the class, Constructor of enum is invoked? or does accessing member like Save and File will invoke the constructor? What happens if there is no argument constructor?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar A class can be loaded without being initialized. So, no, it means that when the class is initialized, each member is constructed. And, as I said, it doesn't matter whether a member is referenced; it gets constructed when the class is initialized. Your second question isn't clear. If no arguments are provided for the member, there must be a no-arg constructor defined, or the enum won't compile. Is that what you mean?

Comment: But in enum we never do new SomeEnum() i.e no explicit initialization! In my case enum has only one variable i.e *instance* and a private constructor with no args. When does this constructor get called?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar The declaration of the `enum` members uses some "syntactic sugar" to generate code. If you declare an `enum` like `Status { GOOD, BAD; private Status() { } }`, it's equivalent to something like `public static final GOOD = new Status(); public static final BAD = new Status();` and that code is executed when `Status` "class" is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Much like the `static() {...}` method, the constructors are invoked when the Enum class is first initialized. All instances of the Enum are created before any may be used.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   System.out.println(Commands.Save.getShortCut());
}
```

In this sample, the ctor for both `Save` and `File` will have completed before `Save.getShortCut()` is invoked.

They are invoked sequentially, as declared in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Both will be created at the class initialization time as others said. I like to point out that  this is done before any static initializers so you can use these enums in static block.