# Java enum evaluations at compile/run-time

Tags: java, enums, compile-time

When does enum value constructors evaluate? At compile-time or
during program execution?

---

In fact, my specific case might be even more nuanced than this so
I will expand on the question.

I have a class,

```
class Instruction
```

which has a `private enum`

```
private enum InstructionModel
```

where `InstructionModel` serves as archetypal examples for
instructions. A bare-bones view would be

```
private enum InstructionModel {
    ADD("add $t1, $t2, $t3", 0x014b4820, // Other params
            ),
    ;

    // Some stuff

    InstructionModel(String example, int sameExample, // Other params
                            ) {
        // Some other stuff
    }
```

Now, the enclosing class (`Instruction`) can create instances of
itself from both Strings and numbers, i.e.

```
class Instruction {
    Instruction fromNumber(int number) {
        // ...
    }

    Instruction fromString(String mnemonic) {
        // ...
    }

    private enum InstructionModel { ... }
}
```

So,

```
Instruction foo = Instruction.fromNumber(0x014b4820);
Instruction bar = Instruction.fromString("add $t1, $t2, $t3");
assert(foo.equals(bar));
```

Now, I could open up the `Instruction` API, so that I could from my
unit tests access the examples encoded into the `InstructionModel`.

**But:** (assuming my understanding is correct) since an enum
constructor is only ever executed once, I could let the value
constructor verify that the String example yields the
numerical representation and vice versa.

Although, I do not want to do this unless it is simply a compile-time
cost. I.e. could I have

```
InstructionModel(String example, int sameExample, // Other params
                        ) {

    Instruction foo = Instruction.fromNumber(0x014b4820);
    Instruction bar = Instruction.fromString("add $t1, $t2, $t3");
    assert(foo.equals(bar));

    // Some other stuff
}
```

without it affecting the end-user?

## Note

In this context the following operation is crucial

```
Instruction foo = Instruction.fromNumber(0x014b4820);
Instruction bar = Instruction.fromString("add $t1, $t2, $t3");
assert(foo.equals(bar));
```

as the `InstructionModel` is not sufficient to ascertain whether two
instances are equal.

## Rationale

For those that question the *why* my reasoning is this:

In comparison with plain JUnit tests, where we'd have to
either encode the knowledge that

> "add $t1, $t2, $t3" <-> 0x014b4820

or make the `InstructionModel` class publicly accessible to access the
examples (or access the examples through methods in the enclosing
class) it felt prudent to let the constructor evaluate that the proper
model is instantiated for a corresponding number.

Subsequently, the code will not does not compile if the `Instruction`
constructors are "wrong".

Comment: Constructors execute at runtime.

Comment: I came to the realization of how to self-answer my question. Create a faulty parsing stage, compile, and see if it caused any errors. I had to execute the program to encounter any problems thereby affirming @EJPs statement that this is a run-time issue

Comment: @FilipAllberg glad to hear you solved, you can answer your question and share with us what you learned... this will make community better `:)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1380979/2568885

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Constructors evaluate at run-time. This means that
the following snippet,

```
InstructionModel(String example, int sameExample, // Other params
                        ) {

    Instruction foo = Instruction.fromNumber(0x014b4820);
    Instruction bar = Instruction.fromString("add $t1, $t2, $t3");
    assert(foo.equals(bar));

    // Some other stuff
}
```

is evaluated at run-time. It does not matter that it is an enum-constructor. Hence, it is only when the constructor is used that it is evaluated.

> Although, I do not want to do this unless it is simply a compile-time cost. I.e. could I have
>
> ```
> InstructionModel(String example, int sameExample, // Other params
>                         ) {
>
>     Instruction foo = Instruction.fromNumber(0x014b4820);
>     Instruction bar = Instruction.fromString("add $t1, $t2, $t3");
>     assert(foo.equals(bar));
>
>     // Some other stuff
> }
> ```
>
> without it affecting the end-user?

No.

Comment: There is no 'empirically' or 'Enum value-constructors' or 'in the context of this question' about it. All constructors execute at runtime. Period.

Comment: I phrased it like that since my own experiments showed it to be that way, but that does not mean that I alone can infer that it applies to all constructors and secondly, there is absolutely a question of context as I am addressing my original question. Ergo: "Although, I do not want to do this unless it is simply a compile-time cost. I.e. could I have (code) without it affecting the end-user?" And the answer to that is "No". I'll happily rephrase it and refer to your better judgement.

Comment: You don't have to 'infer' it at all. You can look it up, or reason it out from first principles.